# What is the proper way to union tables to get set of unique records from all tables?

Tags: sql, hana

I have the following example:

[image: tablexample]

And i don't know how to do a proper union among those tables

Comment: What is a "proper" union?  What is an "improper" union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the issue that the columns are different?  If so, just pad them with nulls:

```
select a, b, c, null as d from t1 union all
select a, b, c, null as d from t2 union all
select a, b, c, null as d from t3 union all
select a, b, c, null as d from t4 union all
select a, null as b, null as c, d from t5 union all
select a, null as b, null as c, d from t6 union all
select a, null as b, null as c, d from t7
```

Comment: If the “unique” records from the question title is an actual requirement then `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL` can be used.